# How to escape a caret passed in the value passed to the RubyGems proxy parameter?

Tags: ruby, proxy, rubygems, escaping

I am trying to install a gem while sitting behind a proxy. The password I have been given contains a caret (^).

My http_proxy environment variable is `user:pass^word@proxy`, which makes git happy, as an example.

When I call `gem install package` I get:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (URI::InvalidURIError)
     bad URI(is not URI?): http://user:pass^word@proxy
```

When I call `gem install package -p http://user:pass\^word@proxy` or `gem install package -p 'http://user:pass^word@proxy'` or the same without `http://` I get

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (OptionParser::InvalidArgument)
    invalid argument: -p http://user:pass^word@proxy
```

I tried to escape the caret with extra backslashes, but they get turned to forward slashes.

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding to the rescue!

```
gem install package -p 'http://user:pass%5Eword@proxy'
```